# Drupal 7 output taxonomy tags depicting the parent in a tree

Tags: view, drupal-7, tree, parent-child, taxonomy

There is a `parent category`, and each of them has a `child categories` for example:

```
1. Products 
  1.1 Milk 
  1.2 Tea 
  1.3 Potatoes 
2. Technique 
  2.1 Vacuums 
  2.2 Oven 
3. Software 
  3.1 Photoshop 
  3.2 Paint 
  3.3 Coral Draw
```

Each parent category has an `image (icon)` in `child categories` are no pictures.

In addition, there is a description of `child categories`.

I try to implement it through the `taxonomy tags`, but the problem with the conclusion of these categories in a tree. 
Write code to display the latest version, I would like to accomplish this with modules, and even better if we can do it with standard features.

I created a `dictionary categories`, and who placed the `child` and `parent categories`. Then I built a tree. 
Upload pictures for parent categories, and set the output through representation. 
To display a list in a tree, I have grouped by category parents.

However, the parent categories I have not found the image. Instead, the images are to print once at the parent category, derived from each child category, while the parent category is not displayed at all.

question: 
whereby it can be implemented in `Drupal 7`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Views module https://www.drupal.org/project/views to show the taxonomies..
views provides various filters to show taxonomies by vocabulary, parent terms, child terms etc. It might help you

[EDITED] : to show only parent terms with their images... just add a filter for parent term and set its value "equal to" "0". It will then only show parent terms.

Comment: I'm already using this module (view and deduce them taxonomy term) 
But it is impossible to display the image, separately for the parent. 
Instead, it is derived from each child. 
Is there a specific solution?